# Push Layout for keyboard

Tags: android, android-layout, tabs, keyboard

I implemented bottom tabs in my application. One of the activities has an EditText at the middle of the screen. Pressing that field causes the screen with tabs to be pushed up. Now I fixed the layout by adding the following code to the manifest file:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"
```

But this causes the whole activity to be fixed. Is there a way I can fix the tabs but push the activity inside it upwards for the keyboard?

Part of the Manifest File:

```
android:name="com.betaclassapps.ghadinews.GhadiNewsTabActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name" 
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"
android:screenOrientation="portrait">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Put your layout in scrollview and try.

Comment: @MD :My layout is already in a scrollview. and now the problem is that the text field is a big and if the user wants to fill it with words some of the words will become hidden behind the keyboard. I tried scrolling but the layout stays fixed.

Comment: you implemented TabActivity or anything else?

Comment: @MD : yes i implemented TabActivity, now TabAcitivity is fixed and it also made all of the activities inside it fixed as well.

Comment: then set `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"` to your main `Tab Activity`. that's it.

Comment: @MD : I previously added this command look at the edited post above. That's the problem the code fixed the tabActivity and the activities inside it. I want the activities to be pushed up but keep the tabs fixed.

Comment: @MD : I fixed it :D by adding adjustPan alone without "|adjustResize".

Comment: #nick28 that is great achievement